# С помощью чего верстать

Tags: html, css, margin

Если сегодня так порицается верстка на margin (вроде порицается, по крайней мере не советуют ее использовать, хотя она по идее рабочая), то на чем новичку нужно учиться верстать, чтобы не переучиваться?

Comment: Кто вам такую глупость сказал?

Comment: вы считаете, что верстать на margin сегодня актуально?

Comment: Вряд ли вы найдете сайт, который не использует отступы, не думаю, что каким-то другим способом(например, через позиционирования), верстать намного удобнее.

Comment: Нужно учить CSS. Если вы собрались выдирать из него отдельные куски и не учить всё остальное, вы так далеко не продвинетесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы имели в виду флексбоксы или гриды, потому что о них идёт спор об использовании, тогда как margin не может не использоватся в вёрстке, это как ширина, есть у всех элементов. Флексбоксы и гриды актуально заменить на колонки Bootstrap4.

Вот самая популярная схема обучения на сегодня:

1) HTML5 + CSS3

2) Bootstrap4 (

3) Jquery

4) CSS,  js фреймворки анимаций и украшательства сайта

Comment: после первого пункта список деградаций